# Adding an activity causes R not to be generated

Tags: android, android-activity, android-appcompat

I am developing an Android application. I've got two pacakages with different activities in both of them. I simply added a new activity to one of the packages, and my R file was deleted and couldn't be recreated. I had a lot of errors like this one :

```
[2015-01-31 11:35:14 - BackOffice] D:\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values\attrs.xml:28: error: Attribute "title" has already been defined
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Which libraries are you using? Are you defining a title attribute in your attrs.xml file?

Comment: I finally get it to work. I was adding my support library from tow diffferent paths